# Magento2 - Add new field to new step in magento 2!

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, onestepcheckout

I'm doing "add new field to new step" in checkout page in magento2, i've added new step to chekout page in magento 2 with name "Pharmacy Questions" [image]

Now, i'd like "add a new field form with input type is text to step "Pharmacy Questions". Add a new field same field "Email address" in step "Shipping" [image]. 
Please, help me, give me a hint! Thank you!

Comment: Have you got an any answer? I also met the same issue.. Kindly share your solution?